# how to create textview singleline dynamically without increasing its height

Tags: iphone

I am using a textview and I want to fix the height to 30. I also want the text to scroll upwards when the text wraps to a new line. This also needs to be done dynamically. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement a couple of things:

You will need to implement a couple of UITextView delegate methods. Probably the easiest (at this point) for you would be to implement the

```
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{
    NSRange range;
    range.location = [textView.text length] - 1;
    range.length   = 1;
    [textView scrollRangeToVisible:range];
}
```

method.  With the code I have put in there.  Let me know if this works for your needs :-)

Comment: Wasnt sure if this routine was called for every character entered, if it is not, then I will edit my answer!